# A simple intermediate step of the proof that $\partial^2 = 0$ in the case of singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

Let $\Delta_q$ be the standard $q$-simplex. The function $F_q^s : \Delta_{q-1} \to \Delta_q$  is the $s$-th face of $\Delta_q$, defined as the correstriction to $\Delta_q$ of $(e_0,\dots,e_{s-1},\hat{e_s},e_{s+1},\dots,e_q)$, the map $\Delta_{q-1} \to \mathbb{R}^q$ that sends $e_i$ to itself for $i < s$ and $e_i$ to $e_{i+1}$ if $i \geq s$.

I'm stuck on trying to prove the following elementary result,

> ***Lemma***. Let $0 \leq   j < i \leq q$. Then $F_q^{i}F_{q-1}^{j} = F_q^{j}F_{q-1}^{i-1}$.

I apologize for the simplicity of the question, but I cannot seem to pinpoint where am I making the mistake, so any help is greatly appreciated.

By a direct calculation,

$$
\begin{align}
F_q^{i}F_{q-1}^{j}(e_l) &= \cases{F_q^{i}(e_l) \ \text{ if $l < j$}\\ F_q^{i}(e_{l+1}) \text{ if $l \geq j$}} \\&= 
\cases{
e_l  \quad \text{ if $l < j, l< i$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l < j, l \geq i$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l \geq j, l < i$}\\
e_{l+2} \ \text{ if $l \geq j, l \geq i$}} \\&=
\cases{
e_l  \quad \text{ if $l < j$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l \geq j, l < i$}\\
e_{l+2} \ \text{ if $l \geq i$}} 
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
F_q^{j}F_{q-1}^{i-1}(e_l) &= \cases{F_q^{j}(e_l) \ \text{ if $l < i-1$}\\ F_q^{j}(e_{l+1}) \text{ if $l \geq i-1$}} \\ &= 
\cases{
e_l  \quad \text{ if $l < i-1, l< j$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l < i-1, l \geq j$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l \geq i-1, l < j$}\\
e_{l+2} \ \text{ if $l \geq i-1, l \geq j$}} \\ &=
\cases{
e_l  \quad \text{ if $l< j$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l < i-1, l \geq j$}\\
e_{l+2} \ \text{ if $l \geq i-1$}}
\end{align}
$$

These don't seem to coincide. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Many homology theories are described by a collection of maps called face and degeneracy maps, satisfying a set of axioms called _simplicial identities_ (you may read more about them at the nLab). The ones you posted are precisely the ones which guarantee that their alternating sum is a differential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not correctly calculate $F^s_q(e_{l+1})$. You have
$$
\begin{align}
F_q^{i}F_{q-1}^{j}(e_l) &= \cases{F_q^{i}(e_l) \ \text{ if $l < j$}\\ F_q^{i}(e_{l+1}) \text{ if $l \geq j$}} \\&= 
\cases{
e_l  \quad \text{ if $l < j, l< i$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l < j, l \geq i$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l \geq j, l+1 < i$}\\
e_{l+2} \ \text{ if $l \geq j, l+1 \geq i$}} \\&=
\cases{
e_l  \quad \text{ if $l < j$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l \geq j, l < i-1$}\\
e_{l+2} \ \text{ if $l \geq i-1$}} 
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
F_q^{j}F_{q-1}^{i-1}(e_l) &= \cases{F_q^{j}(e_l) \ \text{ if $l < i-1$}\\ F_q^{j}(e_{l+1}) \text{ if $l \geq i-1$}} \\ &= 
\cases{
e_l  \quad \text{ if $l < i-1, l< j$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l < i-1, l \geq j$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l \geq i-1, l+1< j$}\\
e_{l+2} \ \text{ if $l \geq i-1, l+1 \geq j$}} \\ &=
\cases{
e_l  \quad \text{ if $l< j$}\\
e_{l+1} \ \text{ if $l < i-1, l \geq j$}\\
e_{l+2} \ \text{ if $l \geq i-1$}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I see it now! I had rewritten this many times, but it seems that I had fixed my mistake already. Thanks a lot!